# How to enable the libattr frature(abbreviated xattr) in linux?

Tags: python, linux, attr

I want to use xattr in python, but found the xattr's keys() is empty, does that indicate the libattr feature wasn't enabled?
I've learned the libattr feature is disabled in ext3/ext4 by default, but how to enable it?
Expect your help!
Thank you~

```
>>> import xattr
>>> x = xattr.xattr('tiger_8a428_userdvd.dmg')
>>> x
<xattr file='tiger_8a428_userdvd.dmg'>
>>> x.keys()
[]
```

Comment: This seems like a kernel configuration issue. You might want to ask [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/) (or [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/)) instead of StackOverflow.

Comment: Thank u very much~
But what's the relationship of them three?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use the following:

`>>> x = xattr.get_all('tiger_8a428_userdvd.dmg')`

Should be better.